# Tanstack Table grouping : Is it possible to disable grouping when there is only one row for the group?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grouping, tanstack, material-react-table

I'm new at using Tanstack table by the use of Material React Table.

My dataset is a list of user with some infos (1st and 2nd rows) and 6th columns that defining a "Scope" object.
So my users can have multiples "Scope" and I want to leverage MRT (aka Tanstack table) grouping to show that.

So I use aggregation to show the number of Scope when grouping Users.

I want to know if there is an option or a solution to prevent grouping when my user has only one Scope.

Here the picture when all groups are expanded (green = ok, red = change I want to made) :
[Screen of my current table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNtkI.png)

My code is pretty standard here but I can't find in the docs how to reach this use case ...

Thanks for your help ;)

What I tried before to ask for help >>> I just read the docs to figure out to disable grouping when there is only one row in the group. Don't find the answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I provided my code in the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after hours of research I got it.
Simply define `getRowCanExpand` props of the Material React Table

Here is the right doc : https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/features/expanding#getrowcanexpand

My custom condition, I don't want row with only one leaf (child) to be able to expand so :

```
getRowCanExpand={row => row.getLeafRows().length > 1}
```

I was misleading by searching "grouping" key word, it was "expand" the key. Sometimes difficult to understand well concept in English (not my native langage).

I hope it helps someone ;)